# Helvetica Neue looks funny in Firefox, it looks like a different font

Tags: css, firefox, fonts

**Helvetica Neue** looks funny in Firefox, it looks like a different font on the same machine. The *font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif*. I googled around and found nothing. I also checked the settings in Firefox and this is what I have:

[image]

**Chrome:**[image]

**Firefox:**[image]

This is the [**URL**](http://rscompanyus.com/) if want to take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of how the font appears in each of the browsers you're comparing